# Variable Service Reference Endpoint in C# and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wcf, console-application, service-reference, svc

Excuse my ignorance if this is something basic, I am somewhat new to the whole C# console application, using a Web Service Reference (WCF).

I am creating an application that will be places as an executable on many different machines and acts as a client to a web service. however, the web service is also installed in the client's local intranet, so the endpoint will change for each location.

I see the web reference endpoint is in the app.config file when adding within Visual Studio, but is there a simple way to change the endpoint at runtime, verify the endpoint is correct and exists, and be able to use the methods?

Also, if this is possible would I still need to add the SVC as a service reference in my Solution or would I call it dynamically?

I am using C# and .Net 4

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the address as an AppSetting and set it after creating your proxy class:

```
Proxy.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("myconfigvaluehere");
```

Comment: I am sorry, but what is the use of a separate proxy class? Do you need to create a class that inherits the SVC return object?

Comment: Or is this created using the svcutil.exe? and just change the endpoint address in the code?

Comment: Sorry, my code might have been misleading.  You don't need a seperate proxy class, just set the EndPoint.Address on your service reference generated using svcutil.exe.

Answer (score 0):

First - there's excellent book about WCF services by Juval Lowy: [Programming WCF Services: Mastering WCF and the Azure AppFabric Service Bus](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=PvNrurEhmiEC&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=wcfwrapper%20juval&source=bl&ots=ChAnMwJ-Ox&sig=ZF9gUUfnqXe1gbjg27edS7OISmE&hl=iw&sa=X&ei=iijqT7XOM8fZ8gPb9ZRu&ved=0CKoBEOgBMAA#v=onepage&q&f=false). He explains along the book about WCF wrapper class that connect to WCF service dynamically using `Endpoint`, `Binding` and all that jazz. But you need to understand WCF background to continue working with it <- and you can do it from the book :)